# É possível criar um iframe de uma parte específica de uma página?

Tags: javascript, html, css

É possível obter uma parte específica de um site, mapeando-a para um iframe?

Já vi algumas soluções usando css, mas não dá o efeito de fixar a região.

```css
clip: rect (top, right, bottom, left)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sim , é, basta colocar o `id` da secção que queres que apereça por default no final do url em `src`. O máximo que podes fazer é esconder o scroll, nota que este scroll não é teu, é da outra página que estás a importar, não tens qualquer controlo sobre ele. Podes no entanto esconde-lo como fiz. Neste caso, a titulo de exemplo defini que quero que apareça o footer

```css
div {
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  }
iframe {
  margin-right:-15px;
  }
```

```html
<div>
<iframe src="http://www.bbc.com/#orb-footer">

</iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Até funciona, mas também retorna outro conteúdo da página, apenas ajustando a rolagem para a seção especificada.

Comment: Como o @Miguel falou, não é possivel fazer mais que esconder o scroll

Comment: Com Iframe não, mas o que daria para fazer é saber qual parte especifica do site ele quer, e no caso pegar a informação que ele quer e alimentar a parte do site dele que quer essa informação, isso sem usar Iframe.

Comment: Você diz pegar o elemento com jquery? Como carregar um documento externo?

Comment: E se o elemento não possuir um id?

Comment: @Miguel Teria como fixar o frame omitindo a barra de rolagem?