# Como fazer scroll em um iframe com referencia a outro url?

Tags: iframe, rolamento

Pessoal tenho um iframe que tem a src direcionada para outra url, sei que nesse caso não posso acessar o conteudo do mesmo por questões de segurança, mas o que eu queria é simplesmente posicionar o scroll eu uma determinada posição

Isso não é possivel?

Tentei:

```
$(".scroll").click(function () {
    var iframe = $('#xframe').contents();
    iframe.scrollTop(400);
});
```

Acima o navegador bloqueia por segurança

Tambem:

```
$(".scroll").click(function () {
    var iframe = $('#xframe');
    iframe.scrollTop(400);
});
```

O segundo não surte efeito

Comment: Veja se ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134090/%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-criar-um-iframe-de-uma-parte-espec%c3%adfica-de-uma-p%c3%a1gina/134095#134095

Comment: @Miguel sua dica ajudou muito, apesar do resultado não ser o que eu gostaria, pelas limitações da empresa que me fornece os dados para o iframe, funcionaria muito bem com json se eles fizessem lá, mas vamos empurrando com a barriga.